# How do I insert certain values, including the customer ID pulled from another table, into a seperate table

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, insert

Okay, so i'm working on my final project for VB.net II. I'm created a project for a hotel stay situation and I have everything working perfectly. I need help however on adding something to it.

I have it to where either your a new guest/customer or a returning. If your new, when you submit the form, it adds the customers information to the database. My Access database has 2 tables: **Customer** and **CustomerStays**.

Now, the primary key in both of them is a field called: **CustomerID**  and they have a relationship tied together in the database itself.

Fields of the **Customer table** include: **CustomerID**, **CustomerName**, **CustomerAddress**, **CustomerZipcode**, and **CustomerTagNumber**

Fields of the **CustomerStays table** include: **CustomerID**, **CustomerDateIn**, **CustomerDateOut**, and **TotalDays**

Here is an image of my main form: [image: Main Form]

When they click total for stay, here is the code that goes through with it

```
 Private Sub TotalForStayBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TotalForStayBtn.Click

    ErrorChecking() 'Sub routine that checks for errors

    If YourGood = True Then 'Only good if you pass the error check

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''ADDING CUSTOMER INFORMATION TO THE DATABASE''''''''''''''''
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        If ExistingCustomer = False Then

            Try

                myconnection.Open()

                Dim str As String

                str = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerTagNumber='" & CustomerTagNumbertxt.Text & "'"

                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

                If dr.Read Then

                    If MsgBox("That license plate tag number already exists. Are you an existing customer?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

                        ReturningCustomerLookup.Show()
                        Me.Close()

                    ElseIf MsgBoxResult.No Then

                        MessageBox.Show("Please re-enter your own license plate tag number and verify that it is entered correctly.")

                    End If

                Else

                    str = "INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerZip, CustomerTagNumber)" _
                        & " VALUES ('" & CustomerNametxt.Text & "','" _
                        & CustomerAddresstxt.Text & "','" _
                        & CustomerZipCodetxt.Text & "','" _
                        & CustomerTagNumbertxt.Text & "')"

                    cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MessageBox.Show("Your information has been successfully added to the database", "Successful")

                    '''''''CALCULATING THE TOTAL'''''''
                    CalculateTotal()
                    '''''END CALCULATING THE TOTAL'''''

                    '''''''ADDING DATES INFO TO DATABASE'''''''
                    **CustomerStaysInsertion()**
                    '''''END ADDING DATES INFO TO DATABASE'''''

                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error inserting your information into the database" _
                                & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Original Error: " & ex.ToString, _
                                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Finally
                myconnection.Close()
            End Try

            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            ''''''''''''''END ADDING CUSTOMER INFORMATION TO THE DATABASE''''''''''''''
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Else

            '''''''CALCULATING THE TOTAL'''''''
            CalculateTotal()
            '''''END CALCULATING THE TOTAL'''''

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Now my problem is the **CustomerStays** information. It runs the subroutine and what I want it to do is use the information of the customer to grab the **CustomerID** in the **Customer** table and place that AS **CustomerID** in the **CustomerStays** table along with the date that they check in and check out and the total number of days staying.

Basically, I need it to insert all of that information with the CustomerID that belongs to the customer that is currently staying at the hotel.

Additional info:

Names for some controls:

Date in - DateInPicker

Date out - DateOutPicker

Total Days - TotalDayslbl

Comment: Yes, the primary key in both tables is called CustomerID. They stay as many times as they need to, and their customer ID stays the same because if they enter in the same information the program will catch that as a returning customer. What they CustomerStays table is for is to keep track of Guests separate stays at the hotel. the same guest can stay multiple times so they CustomerID for each guests needs to be individual to the one guest.

Comment: In this scenario  CustomerID in CustomerStays is called [ForeignKey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) not PrimaryKey

Comment: In any case,  i need to grab the customerid from Customer table to insert it with the other information into the customerid of the customerstays table. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if it is not already set, you need to set the `CustomerID` on the `Customer` table to be an `Autonumber`, so its value is generated automatically for you.

Then, assuming that you don't have concurrent insert in your Customer table, you can grab the last inserted Autonumber executing the following OleDbCommand, just after the ExecuteNonQuery that inserts a new customer,

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
    Dim result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

then the variable `result` should have the last inserted value in the column CustomerID of the Customer table.

Said that, please take advice to change the way you issue your sql commands to the database. 
String concatenation is really a bad practice and should be avoided at all costs.
Just for example, what happen to your code if a Customer is called `John O'Hara`? Notice the single quote? When you concatenate the string in the textbox your query text will result in an incorrect sql statement. But this is just a syntax error, worst is the [Sql Injection scenario described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

This is an example how to write the insert query (but it applies to every query where you need to use text typed by your `malicious` users)

```
str = "INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerZip, CustomerTagNumber)" _
                    & " VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", CustomerNametxt.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", CustomerAddresstxt.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", CustomerZipCodetxt.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", CustomerTagNumbertxt.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

In this way the problem of single quotes is resolved by the framework code and this avoid also the Sql Injection mess.

**EDIT**
For the CustomerStays fields (datetime) use instead this

```
       Dim str As String
        str = "INSERT INTO CustomerStays (CustomerID, CustomerDateIn, CustomerDateOut, TotalDays)" _
                        & " VALUES (?,?,?,?)"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", result)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Convert.ToDateTime(DateInPicker.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToDateTime(DateOutPicker.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TotalDayslbl.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

And if TotalDays is numeric Convert.ToInt32(TotalDayslbl.Text).....

Comment: Okay, now i have the parameter add value in use and it works great. Now i'm having a small data mismatch issue that i would love to get help on. This is till in the original part of my problem with the **CustomerStays** table. I'm having a data mismatch error and i believe it has to do with the dates themselves.

In the database the CustomerDateIn and CustomerDateOut are of the Date/Time type (I'm using Access just as a reminder)

Here is a copy of the code for that subroutine:
http://pastebin.com/fJmGJywz

I have also tried the addwith value 2ndary part without the "#".

Comment: Yes, if you try to insert values in a field that is not text, you need to pass a parameter with the correct datatype. Actually, the culprit is the easyness of AddWithValue that decides the datatype to pass looking at the datatype of the value. In your case you pass strings (the # is an artifact of VBA/VB6) and this in not what the database is expecting. I will add to the answer the syntax required

Comment: Still the datatype mismatch :( I don't know why!
http://i584.photobucket.com/albums/ss289/Firstgamefreak/customerstays.jpg
http://i584.photobucket.com/albums/ss289/Firstgamefreak/Error.jpg

Comment: Thanks for all the help your providing me by the way Steve :). You always seem to be on the lookout for my questions xD